# What is the use of Content-Length header in http response? It is necessary to pass the header? What if the value if more or less than actual content?

Tags: html, apache, http, server

I want to understand the working of Content-Length header and how broswers and servers treat it. I have seen responses without centent-length header and some with content-length. Also, I have seen responses with less value than the actual message body size and browser tuncates the content. I want to know the best practices around the header.

Comment: The specs are in the RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#field.content-length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days, you either need to send an appropriate `Content-Length` in your header, or you need to send your response in chunked transfer encoding.  An HTTP response with less data than expected is an error.